# Highlight regexp case insensitive

Tags: regular-expressions, highlighting, case-folding

Is there a way to use `highlight-regexp` in a case-insensitive way?  I'm parenthesizing an expression in my regexp and refer to it using `\1` later and I want to match this regardless of case.  I'm trying to find occurrences of repeated words (with maybe some other words in between), even if they are differently capitalized, e. g. in

```
One two three.  Four five six four seven eight nine.
```

I would like to highlight the phrase `Four five six four` due to the repeated word `four`.  My approach is this regexp:

```
\b\(\w+\)\b\W+\(\b\w+\b\W+\)\{0,10\}\1\b
```

I will work fine for repeated words with exactly equal capitalization but it does not work if the capitalization doesn't match.

I also tried setting `case-fold-search` to various values but it does not seem to be used for `highlight-regexp`.

Is there any way to highlight my repeated word case?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do what you want with library [Highlight](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary) ([`highlight.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el).

Just set or bind `case-fold-search` to `t` and call any of the regexp-highlighting functions:

- `hlt-highlight-regexp-to-end` - Matches from `point` to `point-max`.
- `hlt-highlight-regexp-region` - Matches within the active region (or full buffer if not active).
- `hlt-highlight-regexp-groups-region` - Like `hlt-highlight-regexp-region`, but also highlights each regexp-group match differently, so you can see the group matches.
- `hlt-highlight-regexp-region-in-buffers` - Like `hlt-highlight-regexp-region`, but in each buffer of a list of buffers.

(You also have the same commands, but with `unhighlight` in the name, for unhighlighting regexp matches - e.g., `hlt-unhighlight-regexp-region`.)

Actually, you have two ways to do this:

1. You can use *overlays* for your highlighting, in which case there is automatically no interference from font-lock. The default value, `only`, of option `hlt-use-overlays-flag` does this. To do this you need not customize any option - it is the default behavior.
2. But if you want to use *text properties* rather than overlays for your highlighting, you can still do it, by (1) setting option `hlt-use-overlays-flag` to `nil` (or to value `t`) and (2) setting option `hlt-face-prop` to value `face`, instead of the default value `font-lock-face`.

Also, command **`hlt-highlight`** combines several commands in one. I bind it to **`C-x C-y`**. If I want to do *regexp* highlighting or unhighlighting I just give it a positive (e.g. `M-1`) or negative (e.g. `M--`) prefix arg, respectively.

Comment: I tried that and found that it works.  Unfortunately unlike the method I used up to now it does not highlight instantly new stuff I type (which is one relevant aspect for me I omitted in my question).  Is there a way to make this instantly reactive on typing?

Comment: I guess you're talking about incremental updating as you type a search pattern. No, it does not do that. You enter a regexp as a complete input, and it highlights its matches.

Comment: No, I talk about incremental updates of the highlights while I change the buffer (type new text in the buffer or change the found spots).

Comment: I see now that you meant that. See my comment for the other answer about that. I don't have another answer for you (other than font-lock). Hopefully someone else will.

Answer (score 0):

`highlight-regexp` is typically(*) only a wrapper around `font-lock-add-keywords`.

For font-lock rules, the variable `font-lock-keywords-case-fold-search` is used to control whether the search is case sensitive or not. However, setting this affects *all* font-lock keywords, so in most cases this is not the way to do this.

A better way to do this is the to replace a font-lock rule that `highlight-regexp` adds, which looks something like:

```
("my-regexp" (0 'face prepend))
```

With

```
(my-matcher-function (0 'face prepend))
```

In other words, call the following is a suitable hook to add the rule (replacing `face` with the face you want to use):

```
(font-lock-add-keywords nil
  '((my-matcher-function (0 'face prepend))))
```

Where `my-matcher-function` is a function that search for `"my-regexp"`, but do that in a context where `case-font-search` is non-nil. For example (untested):

```
(defun my-matcher-function (limit)
  (let ((case-fold-search t))
    (re-forward-search "\\b\\(\\w+\\)\\b\\W+\\(\\b\\w+\\b\\W+\\)\\{0,10\\}\\1\\b" limit t)))
```

(*) When a buffer doesn't use font-lock, `highlight-regexp` use another method.

Comment: Using the default installation on a current Ubuntu, I find neither a variable `font-lock-keywords-case-fold-search` nor `font-lock-add-keywords`.  Since I want to edit pure prose text, I'm not using any other keyword highlighting, so the global change would be a solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that you would like to see incremental change of highlighting as you type your regexp, rather than entering it all at once before seeing the highlighted matches, here's another possibility:

Set option `lazy-highlight-cleanup` to `nil`, and then use Isearch to regexp-search (`C-M-s`). that highlights incrementally, as you type. And when that variable is `nil` the highlighting remains when you exit Isearch.

Afterward you can remove that highlighting at any time using `M-x lazy-highlight-cleanup`.

This highlighting uses overlays, not text properties.

(See also option `lazy-highlight-max-at-a-time`.)

---

If you use library [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus) ([`isearch+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/isearch%2b.el)) then you can toggle `lazy-highlight-cleanup` anytime during Isearch using `M-s h l`.  That can be handy, and it's easier than using `M-x lazy-highlight-cleanup` to remove any existing highlighting.

Comment: Interesting.  But again, this doesn't seem to update when I type new text which would match the search expression.  I would still need to re-type `C-M-s` twice to re-highlight the new stuff.

Comment: Once again I guess I misinterpreted what you said. You apparently mean have the highlighting update when you change the buffer text, not when you incrementally type the search pattern. Font-lock is about your best bet for that, I guess.